# Javascript one function how I see another function variable?

Tags: javascript

The following is javascript code, the purpose is simulating jquery nextAll() function. Now the problem is that when I use function as argument, but it cannot see aLists variable in _nextAll() function.

```
function _nextAll(func) {
    var aLists = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var i = 0;
    var temp = [];
    while (i < aLists.length) {
        if (func) {     //if aLists[i].id = "one" replace func, this work
            var j = i;
            while (j < aLists.length) {
                temp.push(aLists[j + 1]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return temp;
}

var temp = _nextAll(function(){
    if (aLists[i].id = "one"){     //aLists[i] cannot be seen in anonymous function
        return true;
    }
});

for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    temp[i].style.color = "orange";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the *selector* to `_nextAll`, have the function select the first element (or every element) matching the selector, then iterate over each element that comes after it:

```js
function _nextAll(sel) {
  let el = document.querySelector(sel);
  const elements = [];
  while (el = el.nextElementSibling) {
    elements.push(el);
  }
  return elements;
}

for (const el of _nextAll('#one')) {
  el.style.color = "orange";
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div id="one">c</div>
<div>d</div>
<div>e</div>
```

Comment: thanks this work, do you give some explain for your codes , especially what is the mean while loop.

Comment: It selects the element matching the selector you pass in with `querySelector`. Then it keeps iterating over the next siblings of that element with `nextElementSibling` and pushes each such sibling to an array.

Answer (score 0):

you have options to make the two functions see the same variable 
1- you can define the variables outside the two functions and you can access the same from the two function

2-pass all the variable you want to share to the function parameters